# Hybris - Backoffice -Finding XML for its respective view

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

How to find an XML code of an Hybris Backoffice view. I am finding very difficulty its respective XML code.
EX :Login in to Backoffice -->Customer --> payment tab:
Image link:
https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T3Y1C29TR-FCMDCRNV8/1.png
Image link:
And in Payment methods:
https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T3Y1C29TR-FCNPGSASJ/2.png

How can I find its XML file in code and its extension?
I want to customize the view, I mean adding two extra Fields there.

And :
Same in Customer support backoffice also I have some more customization's required there I also I need to find out which XML I have to change.

Comment: Specified URL require login to external service. Please upload images to StackOverflow post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just search the platform for xmls containing the info you need. For example search for "paymentInfos" in all *backoffice-config.xml . There you should find what you are looking for.

```
/platformbackoffice/resources/platformbackoffice-backoffice-config.xml
/customersupportbackoffice/resources/customersupportbackoffice-backoffice-config.xml
```

Of course you have to override this in you own extension and not modify the platform extensions. You can do this by creating a xml similar to any *backoffice-config.xml in you extension naming it yourextension-backoffice-config.xml under /resources folder.